# Is it realistic to deal with a huge undocumented code base for master's project?

Tags: research-process, masters, code

I'm currently pursuing a Master's degree in a STEM field and working on a thesis. For my master's thesis, my advisor suggested I expand the code of the group's  software and add new features to it. However, is very large (some files are thousands of lines long) and hard to read. It consists of many different files  and there are hardly any comments that explain what the functions do,  the meaning of the variables, etc. There's no documentation that  explains what the functions/classes do. It seems like whenever I am focusing on  what a function does, there's multiple functions/variables in it that  are defined in another file and those functions/classes themselves are hundreds  of lines long

While my advisor has mentioned he is open to helping me with whatever  questions I have, most of the problems I'm having are related to the  code, since it's so gigantic and I don't even know where to begin to ask questions. But the prof doesn't know much about the  code, so I have to ask the postdoc whenever I have questions about the  code. However, the postdoc doesn't even know alot of the code (he knows c++, but most of the code was written by a former postdoc), and  told me I should email that former postdoc to  answer my questions about the code.

I've spoken to some people about this, and they've said this is a very bad situation. Should I leave this group and join a new one, even if it means I  have to delay my graduation by an extra semester(assuming that I will graduate on-time if I  continue with this current group)?

It's been a month since I joined this group and I hope to finish by next spring, but I don't know how realistic that goal is.

Comment: For me, key questions are in what topic/field your thesis is supposed to be, and exactly what "*expand the code*" means? If "*expand the code*" means e.g. applying novel algorithms and analysis in your STEM field then it might be fine (but I would still be vary). If it means fixing/adding random stuff to their code base it doesn't sound like a thesis topic for a STEM master's degree.

Comment: As for what he means by 'expand the code', he wants me to add a new function/analysis, so that it handles dynamic, not just static, cases. It's not like I'll just fix or add random stuff. BTW, I mentioned in another comment above that it won't be easy for me to move to another research group even though I'd like to

Comment: My advisor knows about C++ and OOP. When I asked him how much effort he thinks it'll take, he just said it depends on me. He thought I'd understand the code well enough by now since I told him before that I have a decent amount of programming experience (I guess I lied by overestimating my coding skills). This is considering the fact that I joined the group a month ago and did not ask about getting documentation/comments from the former postdoc until recently. BTW, other students have told me they don't recommend working with this advisor. I only joined since I have no other options

Answer (score 3):

I would be very wary of taking on this thesis topic.  There's a huge amount of programming effort here, but you're not trying to get an MS in software engineering, so this will necessarily be a project in which you spend most of your time doing work that is actually outside of your discipline.  Furthermore, there's a risk that either you'll never be able to understand various aspects of the code or that you'll misunderstand things and then make changes that break the code.

Comment: So should I leave this group and join a new one? If I do so, my graduation (assuming that I will graduate on-time if I  continue with this current group) will be delayed by a semester. While it is tempting to leave, not just because of the poor code, but because I'd like to work with better people in a research group, I also do not want to delay my graduation

Comment: @csx I have to second Brian Borchers - this sounds like a very risky undertaking. In fact, IMHO this doesn't sound like it should be an academic thesis project at all (I envisage a software engineering project to be more...systematic & constructive), but rather something you would get paid for. Considering how you've described the situation, I'd personally take the delay.

Comment: Graduate student research assistants are being paid to work for 20 hours a week on a research project.  However, they also generally get the chance to do work that actively contributes to their MS thesis and results in publishable research.  This looks like a lot of work with little chance to do any publishable research.  That's not a very good deal for the student.

Comment: I intend to got to industry after i complete the Master's, so I don't need to produce publishable research. And I want to work on numerical modeling after I graduate, so maybe programming alot is good? But yes, I am not interested in getting an MS in software engineering

Comment: It won't be easy to join a new group. To get the MS,  I need to complete 2 semesters of a thesis course, and I'm currently in the 1st semester. My goal is to get credit for the 2nd semester by completing the thesis next spring. If I leave now, I won't receive credit for the course this semester and it may hurt my gpa. Also, I'll have to re-take the 1st semester of this thesis course in the spring & complete the 2nd semester in the summer

Also, before joining this group, it took a few weeks of asking many profs, and it was only this prof and a couple more who were willing to take me on

Comment: What do you plan to do for your thesis project, since rewriting this code clearly won't lead to a thesis?

Comment: As for what the prof means by 'expand the code', he wants me to add a new function/analysis, so that it handles dynamic, not just static, cases. It's not like I'll just fix or add random stuff. That's our plan for the thesis project. Is this a sign I should leave this group?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a complete answer by any means and this is very far from being my field, but I wonder if there's a possibility of an alternative before you jump ship. Could go to the existing postdoc and ask him if there is any project related to the code base, that you could do in the time available, that would help move his work forward? Then take that idea back to the supervisor, saying that you've talked it over with the postdoc. You might get a bit of informal supervision and you could work on a portion of the code that you could be advised on...if it was technically possible, everyone was amenable etc.

Answer (score 2):

sorry to hear about the difficulties. I used to be a graduate student too and most of my current friends who I interact with almost daily are graduate students. As Greg pointed out, this scenario is very common but certainly far from ideal. I understand your concerns very well since I was in this scenario not too long ago. I was debugging a code written by a earlier post-doc which was in C++ and I was only a novice at C++. My supervisor knew that I was a novice at it and he did not know much about the nitty-gritties of the code. However, I was only debugging the code so did not need enough expertise to add new features. In the end after a couple months of effort I was able to fix the code. That was my story.

However, in your case there are 4 possibilities:

1) Your supervisor envisions some useful features but has no idea how much effort it is to implement it or thinks it may not require much effort but in reality it does.
- (Bad scenario)

2) Your supervisor has somewhat of a good idea of how much effort it is and needs you to do it so that you could use these new features in your work (to follow) and write up a thesis based on it. - (Not a bad scenario unless you have your own different likings for topics you want to work on for your thesis).

3) Your supervisor has somewhat of a good idea of how much effort it is and needs you to do it just as something useful for the group besides your thesis. -(Not a bad scenario unless it takes more than a month or two and absolutely can't go in your thesis).

4) Your supervisor has somewhat of a good idea of how much effort it is and needs you to do it because it will be useful for the group and it is going to take several months and does not help you advance in your field or cannot go in your thesis. -(Bad scenario)

Now, you need to figure out which scenario you fit in broadly. The way to figure out is to discuss and ask questions to the post-doc in the group as well as your supervisor. Ask for a meeting and discuss your concerns (perceived as not the best thing to do- but in reality it is indeed the best thing to do). Many students worry about their supervisors judging them negatively. This worry needs to be suspended since something greater is at stake. Proper communication will eventually lead to good results and in turn a good judgement anyway. Again, you need to discuss and understand how useful this project is for yourself. Then you need to come to a consensus wit others about how long it is expected to take and if it is worth your time to do it. Lastly you should also discuss and put some safeguards in your plan, i.e. a timeline where you expect smaller goals of the project to be completed and if it does not work out the way you want what will be plan B?

And another important thing: If the project or other possible projects that you could take up in this research group do not interest you at all, then you should look elsewhere.

Hope this helps. My best wishes. 
Feel free to ask more questions in response.

Comment: My advisor knows about C++ and OOP. When I asked him how much effort he thinks it'll take, he just said it depends on me. He thought I'd understand the code well enough by now since I told him before that I have a decent amount of programming experience (I guess I lied by overestimating my coding skills). This is considering the  fact that I joined the group a month ago and did not ask about getting documentation/comments from the former postdoc until recently.

Comment: As for what he means by 'expand the code', he wants me to add a new function/analysis, so that it handles dynamic, not just static, cases. It's not like I'll just fix or add random stuff. BTW, I mentioned in another comment above that it won't be easy for me to move to another research group even though I'd like to

Comment: Hmm. Well yes it depends on you but your supervisor should have some idea about how much time it would take for someone with your level expertise. Anyway, going though someone else's undocumented code is never fun unless you are an expert. If you have some confidence to go ahead with the project then you could study the code a little more and come up with a plan to implement the features you are asked to (or maybe fraction of them). If you feel you are making good progress in a few weeks then stick with it till you can. If you feel it is going nowhere, then you could try to change project.

Answer (score 1):

Because I know some people here may not be completely familiar with computer science and "documentation", I'm including this to help people get a better grasp on the scenario.

#### The Context

Somewhere in life, if you work with code, regardless of whether you enter research or industry, you are likely to come across `magic code`.

In most cases, the `magic code` works. No one knows how or why, and the original <s>magician</s> developer has likely moved on. So we have a product that works, but no one knows the <s>incantations</s> methodology that was used to produce the results.

An example of `magic code`:

```
c=["6B8CFF","B13425","6A6B04","E39D25"];a='0155000555540ABEC02EFEFC2EBFBF2BFEA803FFF00A6A002A69A8AA55AAF9D76FFD557FF5555F0541502A00A8AA00AA';with(document)for(i=0;i<96;write('<br>')){h=('000'+parseInt(a.slice(i,i+=6),16).toString(4)).slice(-12);for(j=0;j<12;write('<rp style="padding:1 8;background:#'+c[h[j++]]+'"></rp>'))
```

No one, not even people with knowledge of this language, will instinctively know what this snippet of JavaScript does. [It draws a picture of Mario](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39915/pixel-art-episode-1-display-super-mario)

Writing code like this, the developer will know what they're doing, but no one else will. It is a remarkably efficient time and space-saving technique if you don't have to explain to anyone what you're doing.

The caveat about uncommented code is that somewhere down the line it falls apart and becomes impossible to improve or understand. Someone before you most likely took the code and coded on top of original uncommented code, and kept kicking the documentation down the line for someone else to handle, i.e. saved time now for an eventual time cost later.

At this point, it sounds like the "later" has reached critical mass, where progress cannot continue unless previous progress has been documented.

Leaving the project removes you from the problem, but the problem still exists, and will land in someone else's lap, and if the code is as bad as you indicate, this is application is on development death's door.

#### What you should do about it

You should meet with your advisor to discuss your concerns, as well as these issues:

- This code, while functional, does not follow standard coding convention, and will likely need to be brought up to standards before development can continue.
- Documenting of undocumented code is time-intensive, but ultimately improves future developments Documentation can easily take a fair percentage of the actual time spent coding. If this code has been developed for 4 years, I wouldn't find it unreasonable for a new person to take several months to document everything, or a few weeks to document the important stuff, while leaving the guts intact.
- Possible alternative projects such as retrospective analysis and improvement of the application for improvements, while corrolating your actual topic with how it is being handled by the code.

Comment: I don't think your recommendations are particularly realistic. There are [reasons why this code base was developed without following standard good practices](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17781/why-do-many-talented-scientists-write-horrible-software), and it's a common scenario in academia. Given those reasons, expending a great deal of effort to fix this code base may or may not be something valuable to this research group.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is, yes, it is realistic in the sense that it is a common scenario, and no, it is not realistic in the sense that it can seriously hurt your career and you may not want to get involved in a quagmire like this.

The long answer: scientists are notoriously bad in developing and managing codes. As a result, you often end up like 30 years old undocumented FORTRAN codes that run only a Win95 machine. It may sound exaggeration, but I used to have an old PC because certain software could only be compiled with certain Fortran compiler which has last version running only Win95 or older systems. 
The situation therefore common and obviously it can be very tiresome to fix all this. If you don't think it worth the effort, don't get into it. On the other hand there are cases when the code can do magic and important magic. In this case it is an opportunity to you to became a magician and an expert in a tool that needed by many, but for obvious reasons, can be used by only very few. In other word, if it is an important program, it may pay of on the long term.